# Flow cytometry analysis

Tags: immunology, statistics, flow-cytometry

[image]
I've performed an experiment wherein I have stimulated cells (cell line) with a drug across different time-points - in its unmodified (Drug) or modified form (H-Drug or M-Drug).

All cells are seeded at the same concentration and all are harvested for analysis on the same day.

Method:
[image]

Cells were seeded on the same day. Cells were stimulated at 3:00 on a Wednesday (24 hour timepoint). Cells were then stimulated at 09:00 am on Thursday (6 hour timepoint) followed by 12:00 pm Thursday (3 hour timepoint) and so on until 3:00 pm on Thursday - at this time *ALL* cells were harvested and put into separate tubes according to what they were stimulated with and when e.g. 3 hour M-drug.

All tubes were analysed in sequence to measure the percentage of cells in that test tube that stained positive for that drug (i.e. as a means of measuring drug uptake)

**Question**:
I have measured the percentage uptake of a drug at different time-points (0.5 - 24 hours) for the three drug variants. **% uptake is taken as the % of cells that stain positive for that drug**

What would the correct stat test be? Would a 3-way ANOVA make sense?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I'd just do one-way ANOVA for 3 treatments. In a 3-way anova you'd get stats for the effect of [a and b over c], [a and c over b], and [b and c over a]. I don't think your experiment is designed to test these parameters in relation to one another, but whether the modification differ from the unmodified drug.